# PySpark with SynapseSQL throws error when using queries with restricted keywords in column name

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm querying SQL Database on Azure Synapse Analytics server with PySpark. However, some of my column names may contain restricted keyword(s).

Here, I've prepared a generic example which I could bypass with changing the name of c.Name as something different (restricted word is "close"). However, this is not possible because I need to JOIN 2 tables with columns which contain restricted word.

So, here is my generic example:

```
query = """Select c.Name as ClosedByName, c.Profile_Name__c FROM dbo.table as c"""

# Read from a query
dfToReadFromQueryAsArgument = (spark.read
                     .option(Constants.DATABASE, "server")
                     .option(Constants.SERVER, "workspace.sql.azuresynapse.net")
                     .synapsesql(query)
)
dfToReadFromQueryAsArgument.show()
```

The interesting thing that script will work with following queries:

```
query = """Select c.Name, c.Profile_Name__c FROM dbo.table as c"""
query = """Select c.Name as losedByName, c.Profile_Name__c FROM dbo.table as c"""
```

I've tried to use back ticks as suggested in different posts (`closed`). However, this didn't work. I've also tried other escape/quoting characters. But none of them worked.

So, I need to find a way to avoid this check, either by quoting the text or forcing it to run regardless of using restricted word (close is not the same as closed). I think the check is too aggressive in my case.

Error message:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_6968/4240601845.py in <module>
      1 query = """Select c.Name as ClosedByName,       c.Profile_Name__c FROM dbo.table as c"""
      2 
----> 3 dfToReadFromQueryAsOption = (spark.read
      4                      # Name of the SQL Dedicated Pool or database where to run the query
      5                      # Database can be specified as a Spark Config - spark.sqlanalyticsconnector.dw.database or as a Constant - Constants.DATABASE

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/com/microsoft/spark/sqlanalytics/SqlAnalyticsReader.py in synapsesql(self, table_name)
     40         df = DataFrame(jdf, sqlcontext)
     41     except Exception as e:
---> 42         raise e
     43     return df

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/com/microsoft/spark/sqlanalytics/SqlAnalyticsReader.py in synapsesql(self, table_name)
     37         connector = sqlcontext._jvm.com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.SqlAnalyticsConnectorClass() \
     38             .SQLAnalyticsFormatReader(self._jreader)
---> 39         jdf = connector.synapsesql(table_name)
     40         df = DataFrame(jdf, sqlcontext)
     41     except Exception as e:

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3616.synapsesql.
: com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.SQLAnalyticsConnectorException: Queries with keywords: 
create
alter
drop
with
exec
execute
insert
delete
disable
enable
update
merge
truncate
backup
restore
collate
close
deny
grant
open
revoke
revert are not allowed
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.utils.SQLAnalyticsConnectorOptionsValidator$.validateOptions(SQLAnalyticsConnectorOptionsValidator.scala:118)
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.utils.SQLAnalyticsConnectorOptionsValidator$.validateOptions(SQLAnalyticsConnectorOptionsValidator.scala:68)
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.utils.Utils$.initializeAndValidateOptions(Utils.scala:122)
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.ItemsTable.readSchema(ItemsTable.scala:96)
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.ItemsTable.$anonfun$schema$1(ItemsTable.scala:88)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.ItemsTable.schema(ItemsTable.scala:88)
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.SynapseSqlDataSourceV2.inferSchema(SynapseSqlDataSourceV2.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:303)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.SqlAnalyticsConnectorClass$SQLAnalyticsFormatReader.sqlanalytics(SqlAnalyticsConnectorClass.scala:105)
    at com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.SqlAnalyticsConnectorClass$SQLAnalyticsFormatReader.synapsesql(SqlAnalyticsConnectorClass.scala:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: you have to use [ ] and not backticks in azure

Comment: @nbk - I've tried this [ ]. This works in normal SQL but it's not working wiht pyspark on Azure

Comment: you don't need to escaped closed, it is no reserved word

Comment: @nbk - I disagree. I literally have scripts when I have c missing from word "closed". So, with "losed" it works. IMHO this is a bug. I am trying to find a solution for it

Comment: which error exactky are you getting?

Comment: @nbk - I've updated my post to include error messages and examples of code, which work and don't. Maybe I need to change version of Python or PySpark? I am surprise that I couldn't find other people having this issue...

Comment: this looks more loke a bug in java, but i can't think, why this would be why not simply change to TerminatedByName and go on with your life

Comment: I have also noticed strange quirks like this between Spark pool in synapse and something like spark in databricks. Probably the faulty side is synapse.

Answer (score 0):

This defect is mindblowing.
Looks like the reserved keyword validation in synapsesql performs a direct string search against your query, and any appearance of the given list of keywords will cause this error.

For example:
"select 'dropbox' as test" will cause the error.

Where as
"select 'drpbox' as test " will not.

This is because the former contains the reserved word "drop".

Answer (score -1):

I created a table with column `SELECT` and then queried it using `F-string`

```
# Add required imports
import com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics
from com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.Constants import Constants
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

column_name = "SELECT"

dfToReadFromQueryAsOption = (spark.read
                     .option(Constants.SERVER, "<server>.sql.azuresynapse.net")
                     .option(Constants.TEMP_FOLDER, "abfss://<container>@<storage>.dfs.core.windows.net/sql")
                     .synapsesql("test.dbo.demotest")
                     .select(f"{column_name}")
                    )


# Show contents of the dataframe
display(dfToReadFromQueryAsOption)
```

[image]

Comment: SELECT is not restricted word. Here is list of restricted words:
create alter drop with exec execute insert delete disable enable update merge truncate backup restore collate close deny grant open revoke revert

Comment: so my script works with function: dfToReadFromQueryAsArgument or dfToReadFromQueryAsOption. However, it fails if you use word create - for example in column "CreatedBy".

Comment: Did you tried with F-String?